# different background color for different block of codes

Tags: css, aptana

I am a web developer. I am using Aptana Studio. Can i apply different background colors for different block of codes. especially while doing stylesheets, different backgorund color for header part of css and different for content css. I think it will be easy for me to navigae around. thank you.

Comment: This question should be asked in super user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about coloring the code blocks that you're writing inside Aptana Studio itself (rather than the colors of the rendered objects in the browser) you may wish to install an [Aptana IDE Theme](http://wiki.macromates.com/Themes/UserSubmittedThemes).

This will allow you to choose the color of different keywords, languages and sections.